# How to create integration tests for large projects

Tags: c#, integration-testing

We have created P2P sharing in c# and I want to have some integration tests which tests for example if a file downloaded correctly from sender, and check size, speed etc.

I have tried to send a file and then checked but I can not check this file without running the program.

Any idea how I can create some tests to check data?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start off by the difference from an integration to a unit test. Whereas in a unit test you'll test individual parts in isolation (usually achieved via mocking the dependencies) the integration tests works against the broader (or full) system.

I'm assuming you want to run the integration test in automated fashion. Basically you can just run a test with the unit test framework you're using already (for example NUnit) and when creating the necessary services you don't use any mocks but you inject the actual dependencies.

How you exactly setup the "frame" of the integration test up depends on your project, for example if you are using an IoC library to inject dependencies you might be able to use this one also within the integration tests rather than having to set your services up by hand.

What you have to be careful is also the fact that when you run integration tests it might affect the system you're running it on. So if you're doing something on the file system it's a good practice to make sure to clean up after the test.
I would recommend to create some basic "framework" that fits your project to setup integration tests, that would include the generic code you need to setup the tests to run with your system and maybe creates dedicated folders in a temp directory that will be removed after every test run.

Now to your more concrete question: If I get it right you would need to create a "sender" that will provide the test file you want to download. As part of the test you could deploy this test file to the above mentioned temp folder and configure the sender to provide that file. Then you could create the client that would interact with this sender and download the file to somewhere on your system.

Before you initiate the download you could track the time and figure out how long it took. Additionally you could after the download has finished check it's properties, or compare it to the original file, as I assume it should be identical.

Following some *pseudo-code* that could show the general concept:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Integration")
public void DownloadFileFromSender_ConnectionDoesNotGetInterrupted_SuccessfullyDownloadsFile()
{
   // Arrange - do the setup of files and temp folders, make create sender and receiver
   SetupTestFile(@"Tempfolder\Testfile.txt");
   var sender = new Sender(...);
   var receiver = new Receiver(...);

   sender.ProvideFile(@"Tempfolder\Testfile.txt");

   // Act - Put your actual test here
   var timeBeforeDownload = DateTime.Now;
   receiver.DownloadFile(sender, @"Tempfolder\Testfile.txt", @"Tempfolder\DownloadedFile.txt");
   var totalDownloadTime = DateTime.Now - timeBeforeDownload;

   // Assert - Verify here your assumptions, e.g. download time or file properties
   Assert.IsTrue(totalDownloadTime.TotalMilliseconds < 10000);
   Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(@"Tempfolder\DownloadedFile.txt"));
}
```

Be aware that running integration tests might have a longer time to setup and run depending on the size/complexity of the parts that you are testing. They do not replace unit tests but rather complement them. Due to their difference it's also a good idea to tag them to be able to just run either unit or integration tests.

Again the specifics on how to setup the test environment is up to you and depends heavily on your project you want to test.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer. But one more question about sender. Should I used same functions as I have in sender when I creat a fake sender and client ?

Comment: Yes the goal of the integration test is to verify the functionality of the actual code, thus you would want to use (respectively test) the production code. There are cases where you would need to setup specific things only for the test where you might need some special configuration or parameter, but ideally you'll use the exact same classes and only fall back to some "test specific configuration" if all else fails.

Comment: No problem, if it answered your question feel free to also mark it as acceptance answer :-)